# Retrieving data from many to many relationship and show in json like objects

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, many-to-many, relation

I need to query data from a database with SQL but honestly I'm really bad with SQL. I have many-to-many relations and the result must be in JSON like objects not continuous data. This JSON is the result that I want, where `tags`, `quickTags` and `relatedTo` are many-to-many relations:

```
{
      "idResource": "34613b76-0116-11e6-8d21-32d288336560",
      "title": "Prof. Soledad Rath",
      "description": "Est qui iure sequi repellat rerum iste a. Animi dolorum necessitatibus et id assumenda dolores.",
      "minimumAge": "2",
      "maximumAge": "10",
      "fileName": "fuga",
      "extension": "susp",
      "URL": "https://www.Harvey.com/quia-quia-consequuntur",
      "createTime": "2016-04-12 20:22:36",
      "productionKey": "20106",
      "creatorUser": "Marlin Corkery",
      "creationCountry": "San Marino",
      "resourceType": "tempore",
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "provident"
        }
      ],
      "quickTags": [
        {
          "name": "veritatis"
        }
      ],
      "relatedTo": [
        {
          "name": "Mr. Earl Cartwright"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I just going to give the SQL code from tags table and resources-tags table

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `CTL_Tags`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CTL_Tags`;

CREATE TABLE `CTL_Tags` 
(
  `idTag` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary key UUID format',
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the relationship,\nThis can be defined like:\n \nFather,\nMother,\nUncle,\nAunt,\nEtc.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='This table contains a Catalog of Tags of the relationships ';

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `CTL_Resource_has_Tags`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CTL_Resource_has_Tags`;

CREATE TABLE `CTL_Resource_has_Tags` 
(
  `idResource` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to the CTL_Resource table ',
  `idTag` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key to the CTL_Tags table.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idResource`,`idTag`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_has_Tag_Tag1_idx` (`idTag`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_has_Tag_CTL_Resource1_idx` (`idResource`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_has_Tag_CTL_Resource1_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`idResource`) REFERENCES `CTL_Resource` (`idResource`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_has_Tag_Tag1_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`idTag`) REFERENCES `CTL_Tags` (`idTag`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='this table establishes the amount of tags that a given tag';
```

where the `CTL_Resources` table is

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `CTL_Resource`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CTL_Resource`;

CREATE TABLE `CTL_Resource` 
(
  `idResource` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary key UUID format',
  `idResourceType` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key pointing to the resource type',
  `idCreatorUser` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key pointing to the user who created the resource\n',
  `idModifierUser` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key pointing to the user who modified the resource\n',
  `idCreationCountry` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key pointing to the CTL_country table\n\nthis relationship shows the country from which the resource was created',
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Title of the resource',
  `description` mediumtext CHARACTER SET big5 COMMENT 'Description of the resource',
  `thumbnail` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'url/path to the thumbnail representing this resource.',
  `minimumAge` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Minimum age required to assign  this resource',
  `maximumAge` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Maximum age required to assign  this resource',
  `fileName` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'url/path to the file related to this resource.',
  `extension` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'extension of the resource',
  `coachVisibility` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visibility status :\nVIS = visible\nINV = invisible\n',
  `studentVisibility` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visibility status :\nVIS = visible\nINV = invisible\n',
  `isHTML` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If the resource is HTML this field should contain:\n\nHTML = this resource is HTML\n',
  `studentIndex` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If the resource is HTML and/or is of type TinCan this field should contain the starting page for the student user.',
  `coachIndex` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If the resource is HTML and/or is of type TinCan this field should contain the starting page for the coach user.',
  `isURL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If the resource is URL this field should contain:\n\nURL = this resource is URL\n',
  `URL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If the resource is URL  this field should contain the URL of the resource.',
  `source` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'It contains a description of where the resource was taken.',
  `path` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Path in which the resource is saved physically',
  `status` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACT' COMMENT 'Code of status for internal control\nACT= Active\nINC = Inactive\nDEL = Deleted',
  `createTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Date and time when this record was inserted into the table',
  `updateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date and time of last update',
  `isfolder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentResource` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productionKey` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'production keys for resources',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idResource`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_ResourceType1_idx` (`idResourceType`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_Country1_idx` (`idCreationCountry`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_KnotionUser1_idx` (`idCreatorUser`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_KnotionUser2_idx` (`idModifierUser`),
  KEY `fk_parentResource_idx` (`parentResource`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_Country1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCreationCountry`) REFERENCES `CTL_Country` (`idCountry`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_KnotionUser1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCreatorUser`) REFERENCES `OPR_User` (`idUser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_KnotionUser2` FOREIGN KEY (`idModifierUser`) REFERENCES `OPR_User` (`idUser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_CTL_ResourceType1` FOREIGN KEY (`idResourceType`) REFERENCES `CTL_ResourceType` (`idResourceType`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parentResource` FOREIGN KEY (`parentResource`) REFERENCES `CTL_Resource` (`idResource`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog of resources provided by the KnotionBank';
```

Just in case, I'm working with `ExpressJS` with none `ORM` and my code at this moment is this one

```
var query = `SELECT idResource, CTL_ResourceType.resourceType as resourceType, OPR_User.firstName as creatorUser, CTL_Country.country as creationCountry, title, description, CTL_Resource.thumbnail, minimumAge, maximumAge, fileName, extension, URL, source, path, productionKey
              FROM CTL_Resource
              LEFT JOIN CTL_ResourceType
                ON CTL_Resource.idResourceType = CTL_ResourceType.idResourceType
              LEFT JOIN OPR_User
                ON CTL_Resource.idCreatorUser = OPR_User.idUser
              LEFT JOIN CTL_Country
                ON CTL_Resource.idCreationCountry = CTL_Country.idCountry`


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(query, (err, row, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err)
    } else {
      res.json(row)
    }
  }
)})
```

I will be grateful for any help you can grant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server you can use the FOR XML syntax, which you can use to return an XML object with the same structure as the object you want. Then convert from XML to JSON. For other databases, there are some semblance of JSON/XML libraries, but I've found that they're not terribly adequate at doing what you're seeking.

In case you're not using SQL Server, I recommend building a function that takes uniquely-named columns and references some sort of object definition and builds the object based on the returned results.

Comment: I'm not using SQL Server so I'm not allowed to FOR XML :/  I'm going to check if theres any npm library or I'll have to build a function like you recommend.